# The rectangle of minimum- area enclosing a convex hull has a side collinear with one of the edges of the convex hull

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, analytic-geometry, computational-geometry

I am writing some paper and I have stuck at proof of next theorem. Theorem:

> The rectangle of minimum area enclosing a convex hull has a side collinear
> with one of the edges of the hull.

[example1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0nIM.png)
[example2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0H9m.png)

I have found this theorem in lot of articles, that this must stay, but I have no idea how to prove that.
Any help would be great

Comment: I think that the approach should be - assume that it is not the case and than show that you could modify the rectangle to reduce area by finding a side collinear.

Comment: What is the name of this theorem?